# Laravel Api resource controller json format

Tags: laravel-5, eloquent, laravel-5.5

I managed to change the format for the json response of the laravel resource controller for APIs, i want to make a key -> value response but i cant find the way to remove the brackets:

the response i get is this:

```
{
    "1": [
        {
            "updated_at": 1536147154
        }
    ],
    "2": [
        {
            "updated_at": 1536160598
        }
    ]
}
```

but i want it to be like this:

```
{
    "1":
        {
            "updated_at": 1536147154
        },
    "2":
        {
            "updated_at": 1536160598
        }
}
```

I get the response from an eloquent collection, and then I group it by id, but I don't know how to get rid of the brackets because the values end in an array.

I don't know if I am clear in my question.

Comment: Can you share the code that's giving this output and/or the result of a `var_dump` on the PHP var before converting it to JSON?

Answer (score 0):

Solved it, i removed the groupby and instead, I used the keyBy to assign their id as a key.

Answer (score 0):

Transformers can be used to format json

I used https://github.com/spatie/laravel-fractal to format my json response in controllers